# How to use UIButton to transfer to another Storyboard scene

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue

I have an iPad app, using XCode 4.5, Storyboards, UITabBarController and iOS 6.  I want to have the user tap a button ("New") that will transfer to a scene where a new **Client Info** can be entered.  Yes, he/she could tap the UITabBar and do the same thing, but I need to make this very,very user friendly.

I have been looking at SO for "push" segues, but not sure it would do the job.  Can someone please point me in the right direction? (a URL to a doc would be appreciated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push segues make sense only in the context of a `UINavigationController`.

What you need to do is just to associate your button to an `IBAction` that will change the tab programmatically, something like

```
- (IBAction)switchToClientInfoTab {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; // change 1 to the actual index of your tab
}
```

Segues are now the way of proceeding here.